IDA Pro change color of variables in pseudocode
Very basic Ida Pro plugin that changes color of MyVar123 inside pseudocode window.
Problem is this approach is limited to using ida_lines.SCOLOR_... constants for color. How to define my own text color e.g. #00FF00 or any other way?
I read trough the SDK and i find no function that responsible for custom color codes.
import idaapi, ida_kernwin, ida_lines

class ColorizeVariable(ida_kernwin.action_handler_t):

    def __init__(self):
        ida_kernwin.action_handler_t.__init__(self)

    def activate(self, ctx):

        if ida_kernwin.get_widget_type(ctx.widget) == ida_kernwin.BWN_PSEUDOCODE:
            vu = idaapi.get_widget_vdui(ctx.widget)
            pc = vu.cfunc.get_pseudocode()


            find = "MyVar"

            vu.refresh_view(False)


            for sl in pc:
                sl.line = sl.line.replace(find, ida_lines.COLSTR(find, ida_lines.SCOLOR_DNAME))
                #sl.line = sl.line.replace(find, f'{ida_lines.COLOR_ON}{ida_lines.COLOR_CHAR}{find}{ida_lines.COLOR_OFF}{ida_lines.COLOR_CHAR}')  # broken
                #sl.line = sl.line.replace(find, f'{ida_lines.COLOR_ON}\x0A{find}{ida_lines.COLOR_OFF}\x0A')  #working
                #sl.line = sl.line.replace(find, f'\1\x0A{find}\2\x0A')  #short version

        return 0

    def update(self, ctx):
        return ida_kernwin.AST_ENABLE_ALWAYS




class ida_plugin_container(idaapi.plugin_t):

    flags         = idaapi.PLUGIN_UNL
    comment       = 'plugin comment'
    help          = 'help message'
    wanted_name   = "myPlugin"
    wanted_hotkey = 'Shift-Q'

    def init(self):

        action_desc = idaapi.action_desc_t(
            'myAction',
            'Colorize Variable',
            ColorizeVariable(),
            'Ctrl+R',
            'Colorize Variable in Pseudocode',
            10)

        ida_kernwin.unregister_action('myAction')
        ida_kernwin.register_action(action_desc)

        ida_kernwin.attach_action_to_toolbar("SearchToolBar", 'myAction')
        print('loaded')
        return idaapi.PLUGIN_OK


    def run(self, arg):
        pass


    def term(self):
        pass

def PLUGIN_ENTRY():
    return ida_plugin_container()


Seems there's no option for using RGB color codes or any other means of specifying custom color?
Reading this doc's

A typical color sequence looks like this:
COLOR_ON COLOR_xxx text COLOR_OFF COLOR_xxx
The first 2 items turn color 'xxx' on, then the text follows, and the
color is turned off by two last items.

i discovered an additional way to use predefined color codes trough
COLOR_xxx constants (that happen to not work on IDA 8.3 or i don't know how to use them correctly).
Example this line (also in above code example) does not work.
sl.line.replace(find, f'{ida_lines.COLOR_ON}{ida_lines.COLOR_CHAR}{find}{ida_lines.COLOR_OFF}{ida_lines.COLOR_CHAR}')

Working way to use predefined color codes is:
sl.line.replace(find, f'{ida_lines.COLOR_ON}\x0A{find}{ida_lines.COLOR_OFF}\x0A')

where ida_lines.COLOR_ON is color open tag, \x0A is color code (predefined colors are between hex values \x01 and \x27), ida_lines.COLOR_OFF color close tag, \x0A color code tag repeated (required by ida).
Short version:
sl.line.replace(find, f'\1\x0A{find}\2\x0A')

Good thing though colors can be redefined trough menu Options > Colors > Disassembly in the Text Colors drop-down.
Settings are saved into file %APPDATA%\Hex-Rays\IDA Pro\themes\dark\user.css
Here's the Color code to menu item mapping
Color #  HEX     COLOR_xxx               IDA Menu Item                        CSS Class                         
1        '\x01'  COLOR_DEFAULT           Default                              qproperty-line-fg-default         
2        '\x02'  COLOR_REGCMT            Regular comment                      qproperty-line-fg-regular-comment 
3        '\x03'  COLOR_RPTCMT            Repeatable commen                    qproperty-line-fg-repeatable-comment
4        '\x04'  COLOR_AUTOCMT           Automatic comment                    qproperty-line-fg-automatic-comment
5        '\x05'  COLOR_INSN              Instruction                          qproperty-line-fg-insn            
6        '\x06'  COLOR_DATNAME           Dummy Data Name                      qproperty-line-fg-dummy-data-name 
7        '\x07'  COLOR_DNAME             Regular Data Name                    qproperty-line-fg-regular-data-name
8        '\x08'  COLOR_DEMNAME           Demangled Name                       qproperty-line-fg-demangled-name  
9        '\x09'  COLOR_SYMBOL            Punctuation                          qproperty-line-fg-punctuation     
10       '\x0A'  COLOR_CHAR              Char constant                        qproperty-line-fg-charlit-in-insn 
11       '\x0B'  COLOR_STRING            String constant                      qproperty-line-fg-strlit-in-insn  
12       '\x0C'  COLOR_NUMBER            Numeric constant                     qproperty-line-fg-numlit-in-insn  
13       '\x0D'  COLOR_VOIDOP            Void operand                         qproperty-line-fg-void-opnd       
14       '\x0E'  COLOR_CREF              Code reference                       qproperty-line-fg-code-xref       
15       '\x0F'  COLOR_DREF              Data reference                       qproperty-line-fg-data-xref       
16       '\x10'  COLOR_CREFTAIL          Code reference to tail byte          qproperty-line-fg-code-xref-to-tail
17       '\x11'  COLOR_DREFTAIL          Data reference to tail byte          qproperty-line-fg-data-xref-to-tail
18       '\x12'  COLOR_ERROR             Error or problem                     qproperty-line-fg-error           
19       '\x13'  COLOR_PREFIX            Line prefix Regular function         qproperty-line-pfx-func           
20       '\x14'  COLOR_BINPREF           Opcode bytes                         qproperty-line-fg-opcode-byte     
21       '\x15'  COLOR_EXTRA             Extra line                           qproperty-line-fg-extra-line      
22       '\x16'  COLOR_ALTOP             Alternative operand                  qproperty-line-fg-alt-opnd        
23       '\x17'  COLOR_HIDNAME           Hidden name                          qproperty-line-fg-hidden          
24       '\x18'  COLOR_LIBNAME           Library function name                qproperty-line-fg-libfunc         
25       '\x19'  COLOR_LOCNAME           Local variable name                  qproperty-line-fg-locvar          
26       '\x1A'  COLOR_CODNAME           Dummy code name                      qproperty-line-fg-dummy-code-name 
27       '\x1B'  COLOR_ASMDIR            Assembler directive                  qproperty-line-fg-asm-directive   
28       '\x1C'  COLOR_MACRO             Macro                                qproperty-line-fg-macro           
29       '\x1D'  COLOR_DSTR              String constant in data directive    qproperty-line-fg-strlit-in-data  
30       '\x1E'  COLOR_DCHAR             Char constant in data directive      qproperty-line-fg-charlit-in-data 
31       '\x1F'  COLOR_DNUM              Numeric constant in data directive   qproperty-line-fg-numlit-in-data 
32       '\x20'  COLOR_KEYWORD           Keywords (offset, byte ptr, near)    qproperty-line-fg-keyword         
33       '\x21'  COLOR_REG               Register name                        qproperty-line-fg-register-name   
34       '\x22'  COLOR_IMPNAME           Imported name                        qproperty-line-fg-import-name     
35       '\x23'  COLOR_SEGNAME           Segment name                         qproperty-line-fg-segment-name    
36       '\x24'  COLOR_UNKNAME           Dummy unknown name                   qproperty-line-fg-dummy-unknown-name
37       '\x25'  COLOR_CNAME             Regular Code Name                    qproperty-line-fg-code-name       
38       '\x26'  COLOR_UNAME             Regular Unknown Name                 qproperty-line-fg-unknown-name    
39       '\x27'  COLOR_COLLAPSED         Collapsed line                       qproperty-line-fg-collapsed-line  


The text color in IDA Pro's pseudocode window, you can use the set_node_info2 function
from the
idaapi module to create custom colored text. This allows you to specify your own color using RGB values or hexadecimal .
Check this example:  ` import idaapi
import ida_kernwin
import ida_lines
class ColorizeVariable(ida_kernwin.action_handler_t):
def __init__(self):
    ida_kernwin.action_handler_t.__init__(self)

def activate(self, ctx):

    if ida_kernwin.get_widget_type(ctx.widget) == ida_kernwin.BWN_PSEUDOCODE:
        vu = idaapi.get_widget_vdui(ctx.widget)
        pc = vu.cfunc.get_pseudocode()

        find = "MyVar"

        for sl in pc:
            sl.line = sl.line.replace(find, f'<color=#00FF00>{find}</color>')

        vu.refresh_view(False)

    return 0

def update(self, ctx):
    return ida_kernwin.AST_ENABLE_ALWAYS 

class ida_plugin_container(idaapi.plugin_t):
flags         = idaapi.PLUGIN_UNL
comment       = 'plugin comment'
help          = 'help message'
wanted_name   = "myPlugin"
wanted_hotkey = 'Shift-Q'

def init(self):

    action_desc = idaapi.action_desc_t(
        'myAction',
        'Colorize Variable',
        ColorizeVariable(),
        'Ctrl+R',
        'Colorize Variable in Pseudocode',
        10)

    ida_kernwin.unregister_action('myAction')
    ida_kernwin.register_action(action_desc)

    ida_kernwin.attach_action_to_toolbar("SearchToolBar", 'myAction')
    print('loaded')
    return idaapi.PLUGIN_OK

def run(self, arg):
    pass

def term(self):
    pass

def PLUGIN_ENTRY():
return ida_plugin_container() `

ida_graph.set_node_info2() was renamed to ida_graph.set_node_info() since v7.4 i am on v8.3, according to this site, you did give code example on how to use it.
have you even tested any of this code?
Looks like answer from ChatGPT <color=#00FF00>{find}</color> does not work.
